# I send request in post body in springboot it is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to post body in RESTAPI using spring boot but I cannot. I suffered for long hours till now I also could not find the problem why what is the reason I do not know what mistake I made please help me.

Pojo class

Person.java

```
package com.thila.family.test;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String familyName;
    private String familyMembers;
    private long contactNo;
    public Person() {
            
        }
     
     public Person(int id,String familyName, String familyMembers,long contactNo) {
        super();
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.familyMembers = familyMembers;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    //getters setters
}
```

PersonService.java

```
package com.thila.family.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonService {
  
    private List<Person> persons=new ArrayList<>();
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        persons.add(person);
    }

}
```

PersonController.java

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/fam") 
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        personService.addPerson(person);        
    }
}
```

My JSON request to the body

```
{
   "id":"1",
    "familyName": "panchala",
    "familyMembers":"5",
    "contactNo":"234567"
    
}
```

I got an error

````
{
    "timestamp": "2021-01-02T04:39:55.307+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/fam"
}
```
please help me I don't know why I got this error
````

Comment: The error is specific: You don't have a mapping at `/fam`, which probably means your controller isn't being found. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG` to your properties and post the log from the server console.

Comment: i add the properties file and please tell me how can I add a log for the server console

Comment: Run it, then click "edit" under your question to add it.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to enter for posting this request body?

Comment: localhost:8080/fam

Comment: Where is the request call ? I mean where you are consuming your API ?

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: @Dhiya Can you also add your main method here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I was not figuring out how to solve it, but I decided to see my imports, in case of imports being wrong.

I was importing @RequestBody from:

`io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;`

Instead of importing the @RequestBody from:

`org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*`

If any question, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

In PersonController.java add the following annotation just below the `@RestController` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Only if this is present the controller gets resolved and the path reaches the particular controller method you are trying to call.

Now your URL might look like this : `localhost:8080/person/fam`

Comment: Do you have the application.properties file inside resources folder ? If yes, please share the same.

Comment: application.properties  
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true

Comment: try adding this server.servlet.contextPath=/application/api , and then call this URL from postman : localhost:8080/application/api/person/fam

Comment: I just make a simple get request even this also not working this is not a code or URL problem. example for I try to process the same get request for another project it is working well but the same get request not working here why what is the problem I don't know

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller class

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/fam", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
{
....
}
```

Just a suggestion it would be also good to return a response with a correct Response status

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/fam", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
{
......
 return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

Comment: if I add ResponseEntity it gives the warning like this ResposeEntity is a raw type. References to generic type ResponseEntity<T> should be parameterized.

Comment: As you righty mentioned its a warning, if you are planning to return a value then parametrise it with that value else you can put '?' ```ResponseEntity<?>```

Comment: I've put parameter but it also not working. I really don't know what is the exact problem

Comment: What is the url you are are using? Can you provide the error message and the entire source code?

Comment: This is my url localhost:8080/person/fam

Comment: The code and error message are i mentioned above please find that